# Conflicting t statistics and effect sizes

Tags: t-test, effect-size, cohens-d

Based on Levene tests that were significant at p < 0.001, I'm doing Welch's t-tests on log transformed data with large group sizes (still slightly non-normal).  For some reason, the effect sizes I'm getting (regardless of which effect size I use) seem to contradict the results of the Welch's t. However, the effect sizes make sense based on Student's t-test. See table below for clarification.

---

[image: Notice how the smaller Welch's t (but not Student's t) goes with larger effect sizes.]
Notice how the smaller Welch's t (but not Student's t) goes with larger effect sizes.

---

My questions are:

A) What is a possible work around?

B) Is there an effect size designed for use with Welch's t/unequal group variance and/or unequal group size?

C) Are you aware of any literature on the subject?

Comment: Could you please indicate where you find "effect sizes" in this table?  Exactly how are you defining them?  What specifically do you want to "work around"?

Comment: The effect sizes are Glass's delta, Hedges' g, Cohen's d, and Cohen's d based on Rosenthal and Rosnow (2008) on the right side of the table. Those are all rather common effect sizes, with the exception of the last, which is cited. To your question about a work around, is there not an issue with the magnitudes of the Welch's t tests not corresponding to the effect sizes? If there is an issue, then what is an alternative effect size? Or, less preferable, what is another test statistic instead of Welch's t for unequal group variances?

Comment: The disconnect for me is that these statistics you cite aren't relevant to the Welch statistic. G and D use pooled variances, which implicitly assumes a homoscedastic model.  Your calculation of Delta uses only the SD in group 2, whereas the SD in group 1 is driving the Welch statistic.  Perhaps your calculation of Delta should reverse the groups. (+1 because there are some real questions here and you have helpfully clarified them.)

Comment: Thoughts on using the common language effect size? It's supposed to be relatively robust to non-normality and unequal group variance. I had the same issue with it (not shown).

Comment: The CLES is appropriate for rank-based alternatives to the t-test, such as the [Mann-Whitney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Common_language_effect_size). Assuming symmetric group distributions and nearly equal variances, it could reasonably be applied to a t-test result, but otherwise it does not express what a t-test actually measures.

Comment: Actually, CLES is fine for t-tests (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3840331/?report=classic).

Comment: That result assumes the difference of Z-scores is normally distributed. From what I can tell, the "equivalence" between Cohen's D and the CLES requires (among other things) an *exact* normal distribution of each sample mean and may be sensitive to departures from that requirement.  That takes us right back where we were: you need to assume symmetric group distributions, nearly equal variances, and reasonably small kurtoses before you can reasonably interpret the CLES as a t-test effect size.